# Knife Project leaves creases

Tags: modeling

I have been modeling an aircraft in Blender, however, when I try to cut out the doors for the aircraft using the Knife Project function, it leaves these "creases" on the mesh surface. I am using a mesh with Shade Smooth and Auto Smooth on 30 degrees.

Before knife projecting:

[image]

After knife projecting:

[image]

I would also like to know how to get rid of the existing creases, if possible. Can anyone help?

Thanks!